# Django unicode objects from Angular request

Tags: python, angularjs, django, unicode

When I call a post request from angular and pass a data then receive in django views, the data becomes an object with unicode keys and values.

Sample.

```
//from angular
$http.post("url_here",{"name" : "alde","grade" : 94})

//views.py
data_from_angular = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
print(data_from_angular)
>>>> {u'name' : u'alde', u'grade' : u'84'} // this is the problem
>>>> {'name' : 'alde', 'grade' : 84} // I want this result so that I can have the 'grade' as number not unicode.
```

I hope that you can help me with this. Thanks!

**EDIT**

The problem is in my JSON data. the number 84 was denoted as string. Thanks to @Sudlip for pointing my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The u-prefix just means that you have a Unicode string. When you really use the string, it won't appear in your data.

If you really wish to convert it to normal string you can convert both key and value using dictionary comprehension and `str` keyword.:

```
data_from_angular = dict((str(k), str(v)) for k, v in data_from_angular.items())
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Sudip. I see, you convert all the key and value into string, but what about the 'grade'? I want it to be a number.

Comment: @aldesabido Can you show the original JSON data. It seems 84 is denoted as string instead of number. It has nothing to do with unicode.

Comment: @Sudlip got it now. the number 84 is "84" in JSON data. my bad. tsk2. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
data_from_angular = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
another_dict = dict()
for k, v in data_from_angular.iteritems():
    if v.isdigit():
        another_dict[k] = v
    elif v.isalpha():
        another_dict[k] = v
    else:
       # do something here
```

I prefer this than clever oneliners because after six months down the lane one fool is gonna look into that code and ask what this oneliner doing here..? And that fool could be anyone in including yourself! 
This is drawn from y personal experience